# Cannot restore Postgresql databases got "database already exists" error

Tags: postgresql

I have take backup by `pg_dumpall > test.out`
and test.out successfully generated, hence backup completed.

I have used command  `psql -f test.out postgres` for restore 
But got following errors with restoring backup:

```
databases already exists
relation "products" already exists
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "products_pkey"
```

I actually want to replace the data in the existing db with backup. How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the database you're trying to restore already exists.

You can run a `DROP DATABASE database_name` command that will delete your existing database and then you can run your test.out file.

Or you can run `pgdumpall --clean > test.out` and then run the resulting file.  The clean flag will make the resulting files have the DROP DATABASE command in them.

Comment: `pgdumpall --clean > test.out` is worked for me, thank your @Gregory Arenius

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the bellow command ?

```
 psql -h localhost -U [login role] database_name -f /home/database.backup
```

Comment: No, it is not working because I'm working with multiple databases that is  I am creating a separate db for each & every user. So I cannot take backup of every database one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I think a flow like this might help, because we don't want drop the database each time we call the backup file.

First, we need to create a backup file using the `--format=custom` [`-Fc`] to restore it using `pg_restore`. We can use a connection string `postgresql://<user>:<pass>@localhost:5432/<dbname>` and replace `<user>`, `<pass>`, and `<dbname>` with your information.

```hs
pg_dump -v -Fc \
postgresql://<user>:<pass>@localhost:5432/<dbname> \
> db-20211122-163508.sql
```

To restore we will call it using `--clean` [`-c`] and `--create` [`-C`] to drop the database before restoring. Replace `<user>`, `<host>`, `<port>`, and `<dbname>` with your information.

```hs
pg_restore -vcC \
-U <user> \
-h <host> \
-p <port> \
-d <dbname> \
< db-20211122-163508.sql
```

This way you don't need to use clean when you create the backup file.